# C# Resources object null, Images FileNotFound exception ONLY at RUN Time in WeifenLuo WinFormsUI (LogExpert context)

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a feature in LogExpert https://logexpert.codeplex.com/
Since LogExpert uses a 3rd party dll for dockpanel called WeifenLuo WinFormsUI (https://github.com/dockpanelsuite/dockpanelsuite), this dll is being referenced in LogExpert.

In the WinformsUI, while coding, I am able to use 
 _imageButtonClose = Resources.DockPane_Close; whereby DockPane_Close is an bitmap image.
However at run time, all the objects/elements of Resources are either null, or the images are marked as an error FileNotFound exception even if the images are rightly embedded in the Resources.resx.

Any help on this, will be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to find the issue.

There was a conflict of the language set in the assemblies. So I changed all the language to neutral in the assembly GUI of the project, and here it goes to working fine.